# Making an iframe video stop after closing the modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a website that uses the code from [this tutorial](http://azmind.com/bootstrap-tutorial-modal-video/) to open a modal that displays an iframe to play a youtube or vimeo video.

The problem is, as stated in the comments on the link, it doesn't include the code to stop the video from playing after the modal has been closed (by either hitting the close button or clicking on anything exterior to the video. I'm a novice when it comes to JS so I've attempted every recommendation in the comments but still nothing works. I'm assuming their instructions are assuming a better knowledge of JS to get their suggestions running. So if you could, please "explain like I'm 5".

Here's the code for the JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$('.launch-modal').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $( '#' + $(this).data('modal-id') ).modal();
});

});
```

Here's the code for the HTML modal:

```
        <!-- MODAL-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-video" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-video-label">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="modal-video">
                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cp-Tt3aOYVY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                                <br><br>
                                <h4 class="section-heading">Lorem Ispum</h4>
                                <hr class="primary">
                                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here's the CSS code:

```
.modal-backdrop.in {
opacity: 100;
background: white;
}

.modal-content {
background: none;
border: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0; -webkit-border-radius: 0; border-radius: 0;
-moz-box-shadow: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none;
color: black;
}

.modal-body {
padding: 0 25px 25px 25px;
}

.modal-header {
padding: 25px 25px 15px 25px;
text-align: right;
}

.modal-header, .modal-footer {
border: 0;
}

.modal-header .close {
float: none;
margin: 0;
font-size: 36px;
color: black;
font-weight: 300;
text-shadow: none;
opacity: 1;
}

.modal-dialog {
width: 80%;
margin: 0px auto;
color: black;
}
```

Super appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Seeking help from my closest coder relative, he was able to resolve all issues by replacing the JS code with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.launch-modal').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $modalElement = $('#' + $(this).data('modal-id'));
        $modalElement.modal();
        var $iframe = $modalElement.find('iframe')[0];
        $modalElement.on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $iframe.src = $iframe.src; 
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the actions bound to your button and adding another jQuery event to flag when you click the close button:

```
$("#closebutton").click(function(){
   $("iframe").remove();   //For Safety
   $(".modal").remove();
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by removing the actions bound to the button?

    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">

Removing the data-dismiss tag?

Sorry, please explain like I'm 5.

Comment: Remove line 6 and replace it with <button id="#closebutton" type="button" class="close">

Comment: <button id="#closebutton" type="button" class="close"> did not work, however when I changed the id to "closebutton" it almost works. It would close the iframe but the white modal screen would remain over the page...What this also doesn't resolve is the case of clicking on the modal window, which also closes the modal but maintains the video playing.

Comment: Unless you have **closebutton** assigned to the id of another element, there is no reason that clicking inside the modal window should close it. But anyway try assigning a unique id to your modal window and calling **$('#uniqueid').remove()** in **$('#closebutton').click()**.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Nash, this didn't work but I posted the easiest and working solution after consulting with another dev.

Comment: `$("iframe").remove();` and there goes any other iframe in the page :-D

Comment: Also, it would prevent the modal to be opened again so that's definitely a bad idea to do `$(".modal").remove();` as well